# Add an object inside an array of objects every X objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[

 {_id: "59b6433532b60cfc0a253cec", description: "", imagepath: 
 "https://xxx.1", likes: 0, downvotes: 0}

 {_id: "59b6433532b60cfc0a253ceb", description: "", imagepath: 
 "https://xxx.2", likes: 0, downvotes: 0}

 {_id: "59b6433532b60cfc0a253cea", description: "", imagepath: 
 "https://xxx.3", likes: 0, downvotes: 0}

]
```

This array is getting bigger when using pagination (every `10` objects another `10` are being added to the array and so on).

How i can inject a new object inside the array when the array length is  20, 40, 60 and so on?

expected output:

```
[

 {_id: "59b6433532b60cfc0a253cec", description: "", imagepath: 
 "https://xxx.1", likes: 0, downvotes: 0}

 {_id: "59b6433532b60cfc0a253ceb", description: "", imagepath: 
 "https://xxx.2", likes: 0, downvotes: 0}

 {_id: "59b6433532b60cfc0a253cea", description: "", imagepath: 
 "https://xxx.3", likes: 0, downvotes: 0}

 ... <--- objects are now 20 
 {new object 1}
 ... <--- objects are now 40
 {new object 1} <--- same object as above
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by `How i can inject a new object inside the array when the array length is ex. 20?`

Comment: when the objects inside the array are 20, 40, 60 and so on, i want to inject a new object like `{type: 'blog_post'}`

Comment: Provide an expected output.

Comment: i edited the question, added expected output

Comment: Ok, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.length % 20 === 0` on each retrieval of data or in a loop, according to how you want the new object to be inserted. Using `modulus` for `20` and comparing with `0` will add the new object when length is `20, 40, 60, ...`.

```js
var data = [

 {_id: "59b6433532b60cfc0a253cec", description: "", imagepath: 
 "https://xxx.1", likes: 0, downvotes: 0},

 {_id: "59b6433532b60cfc0a253ceb", description: "", imagepath: 
 "https://xxx.2", likes: 0, downvotes: 0},

 {_id: "59b6433532b60cfc0a253cea", description: "", imagepath: 
 "https://xxx.3", likes: 0, downvotes: 0}
];

var modCount = 0;
var objToInject= {type: 'blog_post'};

//after each retrieval of the JSON array as in data, check if length is 20,40,60,... and so on
if((data.length - modCount) % 20 === 0){
  data.push(objToInject);
  modCount++;
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when `data.push(objToInject)` the data.length is getting bigger by `1` so when modulus fires again it won't work. I'm using it for infinite scroll so the data is not being resseted.

Comment: Yes, it will not work once the length is 20 a object is added and now when length becomes 40 another object will be added. This is what you needed right?

Comment: that's the problem, the data is coming in batches of `10`, when length is `20` modulus will fire, then the data length is `21`, another batch is coming, data length now is `31`, another batch is coming length is `41` so modulus won't fire again.

Comment: Well @StathisNtonas check now. i have added a counter now `modCount`

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

The best way to handle this is to use array reduce

[Read more about array reduce here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=a)

**Example**

In the following example, I will be adding the text **"test"** after every 4th index.

```
var mainArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var newArray = mainArray.reduce(function(carry, value) {
     if(carry.length % 4 === 0) {
        carray.puh('test');
     }
     carry.push(value);
     return carry;
}, []);
```

You can use the same to get the desired result by adding your object in case of string test.